# C++ sending image but seemed failed

Tags: c++, linux, image, http

I am implementing a Web server to send images to a client. When the client browser sends requests for images for the html page, the server intends to send the requested image back, or so it should have been doing.
This is my code of sending the HTTP response. fd is the source file descriptor, cfd is the client socket descriptor, all fine without notable errors.

```
::send(cfd, firstLine.c_str(), firstLine.length(),0);  // HTTP/1.1 200 OK
response.addHeaderDate();  // Date: xxxxxxxxx
int fd = response.ffd;  // file descriptor
// measure file size
int file_size;
file_size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
response.addHeaderLength(file_size);  // Content-Length: xxx
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
// headers
for (auto &item : response.headers) {
    const std::string &key = item.first, &val = item.second;
    ::send(cfd, key.c_str(), key.length(), 0);
    ::send(cfd, ": ", 2, 0);
    ::send(cfd, val.c_str(), val.length(), 0);
    ::send(cfd, "\r\n", 2, 0);
}
::send(cfd, "\r\n", 2, 0);   // blank line after headers
char buf[4096];
while (true) {
    int len = read(fd, buf, 4096);   // read from target file
    if (len <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    write(cfd, buf, len);   // write to socket
}
close(fd);   // close file
```

I let the image to be also written to a local file, and the png image displays just fine in gnome's picture explorer.
I turned on my little server and test it with Chrome. It shows this:
[browser screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Rqt.png)
Chrome shows a broken image icon at the place where I put my img tag. The html file is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
testtest....
<img src="/assets/1.png">
</body>
</html>
```

I turned to the developper tool of chrome. Checked Content-Length field in headers, which says 16996, the exact number of bytes of the image.
Turned to a yet more powerful tool wireshark. It says file data is 16996 bytes, with an 'Expert Info' saying:

```
[Expert Info (Note/Malformed): HTTP body subdissector failed, trying heuristic subdissector]
    [HTTP body subdissector failed, trying heuristic subdissector]
    [Severity level: Note]
    [Group: Malformed]
```

This is also found in the http package for the html file. I believe it states the root of the problem since the message is not shown in other http packs, while I do not quite understand it. I guessed it was about I did not send '\0' when the package is fully transmitted. I tried this and still does not work.
I am new to servers and network programming. Thanks for reading and please help. This is really a pain in the ass.

Comment: `write(cfd, buf, len);   // write to socket` will probably not return `len` if you are sending a big picture in non-blocking mode. Check the return value from `write`. If it's less than `len` you need to continue writing from where it stopped.

Comment: Not sure I get your idea. '''len''' is returned from '''write''', intending to write the same number of bytes as it is read out of the image in every iteration.

Comment: "_`len` is returned from `write`_"  - But you don't take care of that so how do you know? Something like this would be better: `ssize_t written = 0;
ssize_t current;

while( written<len && (current=write(cfd, buf+written, len-written)) != -1) {
    written += current;
}`

Comment: Are you using blocking or non-blocking sockets?

Comment: I did that, and it still does not work. Many thx!!!

Comment: I am using non-blocking sockets

Comment: Then I should try the code I wrote above just to make sure everything gets written. Also check if written==len after the loop to make sure.

Comment: I must read more about nonblocking and asynchronous and all that...

Comment: I figured it out...

Comment: It was the response header. Date attribute string had one more \n...

Comment: Brilliant! Good job!